# Not seeing any Fields for a non-Count Y-Axis aggregation

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I'm trying to graph out average response time from http logs. When I go to Visualize and try either a bar or line graph, any time that select a different Aggregation type besides Count(ie Average, Sum, Max, etc), I never get any values in the Field drop down. I believe that the X-Axis should/could just be a Date Histogram.

My query looks like this: "host:'hostname' AND file:'access.log'", which generates a ton of results as a Count, but again, can't seem to figure out how to graph out that other trend over time(outside of a count). I can confirm all my fields are being indexed.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that a Lucene query?  If so, you need something after 'host:'

Comment: Sorry I had tried to make it look like I had a placeholder instead of one of my real hostnames(but the syntax wasn't right for here), but yes I do have a valid hostname there.

Comment: Just tried this with a real example on my system.  I could only get it to work when I had quotes around the values.  Eg, **host: "hostnamehere"AND file: "access.log"**

Answer (score 4):

The issue in this case came down to mappings, and how the fields were all being interpreted as strings, which makes it impossible to do any of the other number related Aggregations. The only way I found this out is via a tweet from Rashid(the lead dev of Kibana) [tweet from Rashid to me](https://twitter.com/rashidkpc/status/576583631918927872).

Essentially, as documented in the grok docs, I needed to define the mapping type:

```
%{NUMBER:request_time}
```

Became:

```
%{NUMBER:request_time:float}
```

After re-indexing and re-mapping, now my fields are mapping to the right type, and now I can do number based aggregations.