# Plot actual value on y axis in kibana 4

Tags: graph, plot, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I want to plot time on x axis and a numeric field 'f' occurring at that time on y axis in kibana 4.
I have changed the data type of 'f' to integer and I can confirm that it has changed from kibana index settings.

However, the only aggregation options available for Y axis are count/min/max/sum etc. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120199/how-to-create-value-over-time-line-chart-in-kibana-4) has an answer for plotting sum but I'm interested in plotting actual values.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29129044/2599522).

tl;dr
The data you want to plot, are not numbers.

1. Update your grok filter to something like this `%{NUMBER:time:float}` instead of whatever you have.
2. Re-index/re-hash your elasticsearch (i just deleted my data and restarted the whole thing)
3. Goto Kibana4 -> Visualize -> New line graph
4. In *Y axis* select *max* and in the field, select your number field.

Answer (score 1):

Kibana is plotting a bucket, e.g. every minute.

As such, aggregations are in order.  I frequently plot average and max on the same chart to give me a good overview.

If you reduce the time period, the buckets get smaller, but I don't think you can ever make them "just 1 document".